# How do we evaluate $\int_0^\pi \frac{x \cos x}{(1+\sin x)^2} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

How do we evaluate

$$\int_0^\pi \frac{x \cos x}{(1+\sin x)^2} dx$$
I tried integration by parts taking $x$ as my first function and the rest second but not getting the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:
 Treat $x$ as the first function and use integration by parts to get: $ \int_0^\pi \frac{x \cos x}{(1+\sin x)^2} dx= x (-(1+\sin x) ^{-1})|_{0}^{\pi}-\int_0^\pi - (1+\sin x)^{-1}dx$
In the 2nd integral, use $\sin x = \frac{2 \tan (x/2)}{1+\tan ^2(x/2)}$ 
Can you take it from here?

Comment: you missed the exponent of the last integral, right ?

Comment: @Physor: Thanks. Revised.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Integrate by part with $$u(x)=x\quad \text{and}\quad v'(x)=\frac{\cos(x)}{(1+\sin(x))^2}.$$

Comment: Thanks @Surb for your help

Answer (score 1):

**Another hint**:

For the resulting integral, use the substitution
$$t=\tan \frac x2,\qquad\mathrm dx=\frac{2\,\mathrm dt}{1+t^2}$$
and express $\sin x$ in function of $t$.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{aligned}\int_0^\pi \frac{x \cos x}{(1+\sin x)^2} d x = & -\int_0^\pi x d\left(\frac{1}{1+\sin x}\right) \\
= & -\left[\frac{x}{1+\sin x}\right]_0^\pi+\int_0^\pi \frac{1}{1+\sin x} d x \\
= & -\pi+\int_0^\pi \frac{1-\sin ^2 x}{\cos ^2 x} d x \\
= & -\pi+\int_0^\pi\left(\sec ^2 x-\tan x \sec x\right) d x \\
= & -\pi+[\tan x-\sec x]_0^\pi \\
= & 2-\pi
\end{aligned}
$$