# Integrating$ \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac {x \cos x} {(1 + \sin x)^2}$.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

I have been trying to solve this question for a while now.
Tried splitting the integral into $2$ parts: $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac {x \cos x}{(1 + \sin x)^{2}} dx+\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi} \frac {x \cos x}{(1 + \sin x)^{2}} dx.$$

I tried using the same method without splitting it into $2$ parts as well. I couldn't get to the final answer, which is $2-\pi$.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please enclose your formuls with dollar signs ($$) in order to disply them.

Comment: Hint: integrate by parts.

Comment: This page may help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3816306/how-do-we-evaluate-int-0-pi-fracx-cos-x1-sin-x2-dx?noredirect=1

Answer (score 1):

Take $v$ $=$ $(cos(x))/(1+sin(x))^{2}$ and $u$ $=$ $x$. Now try to apply integration by parts to solve it. By the way, I am helping you to solve this question. So, apply the formula for integration by parts. You will get $x×\int_{0}^\pi [(cos(x))/(1+sin(x))^{2}]dx$ $-$ $\int_{0}^\pi [\frac {d}{dx}(x)×\int_{0}^\pi [(cos(x))/(1+sin(x))^{2}]dx]dx$. Now you can easily solve it by substituting $sin(x)$ $=$ $u$. And you will get $cos(x)dx$ $=$ $du$.

Answer (score 1):

$$I=\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac {x \cos x} {(1 + \sin x)^2}$$

Integrating by parts;

$$I=x\int \frac { \cos x} {(1 + \sin x)^2}\,dx-\int 1 \int \frac { \cos x} {(1 + \sin x)^2}\,dx\,dx$$

Consider $$J=\int \frac { \cos x} {(1 + \sin x)^2}$$

Put $\sin x=t$ and $\cos x\,dx=dt$,

$$J=\int \frac { 1} {(1 + t)^2}\,dt=\frac{-1}{t+1}+c \implies J=\frac{-1}{sinx+1}$$

$$I=\frac{-x}{sinx+1}-\frac{2(1+cosx)}{sinx+cosx+1}|_0^{\pi}=2-\pi$$